# How to convert XML to object when some attributes are missing?

Tags: xml, powershell

#### The Problem

I'm trying to convert an XML list of locations to a set of objects.

The XML file has one Location element per location. The XML attributes contain the the object property values.

I want some of the target properties to have a different name from the source attributes.

Later I want to serialize the objects to a CSV file, so the order of the properties is important.

Here is a sample of two locations to illustrate the problem:

```
[xml] $InputXml = @'
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>

<CTLocations xmlns="http://www.cartrawler.com/">
<Country code="AL" name="Albania" continent="Europe">
<Location Id="7188" Name="Tirana Airport" Lat="41.42108838" Lng="19.71271276" CountryCode="AL" Address="Tirana Airport Muhamet Gjollesha Str., Muhamet Gjollesha Str., Tirana" CityName="Tirana" Airport="1" AirportCode="TIA" RailwayStation="0"/>
<Location Id="30768" Name="Tirana Downtown" Lat="41.332" Lng="19.832" CountryCode="AL" Address="Rruga E Durresit. Nr 61, Tirana" CityName="Tirana" Airport="0" RailwayStation="0"/>
</Country>
</CTLocations>
'@
```

#### Partial Solution

My solution works for elements with a complete set of attributes, but fails when any of the attributes is missing.

I'm using [Select-Xml](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh849968.aspx) cmdlet to select the important elements, and [PSCustomObject](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.management.automation.pscustomobject%28v=vs.85%29.ASPX) to create an object with ordered, renamed properties.

```
Select-Xml -Xml $InputXml -XPath '//ns:Location' -Namespace @{ns = 'http://www.cartrawler.com/'} |
% {
  $n = $_.Node

  [PSCustomObject] @{
    LocationCode = $n.Id
    LocationName = $n.Name
    Latitude = $n.Lat
    Longitude = $n.Lng
    CountryCode = $n.CountryCode
    FormattedAddress = $n.Address
    CityName = $n.CityName
    ServesAirport = $n.Airport
    AirportCode = $n.AirportCode
    ServesRailwayStation = $n.RailwayStation
  }
}
```

#### Strict Mode Results

When I have strict-mode set:

```
Set-StrictMode -Version 3.0
```

The first element contains all the attributes, so is converted to an object:

```
LocationCode         : 7188
LocationName         : Tirana Airport
Latitude             : 41.42108838
Longitude            : 19.71271276
CountryCode          : AL
FormattedAddress     : Tirana Airport Muhamet Gjollesha Str., Muhamet Gjollesha Str., Tirana
CityName             : Tirana
ServesAirport        : 1
AirportCode          : TIA
ServesRailwayStation : 0
```

The second element lacks the AirportCode attribute, so PowerShell raises an exception instead:

```
Property 'AirportCode' cannot be found on this object. Make sure that it exists.
At line:16 char:3
+   [PSCustomObject] @{
+   ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
    + CategoryInfo          : NotSpecified: (:) [], PropertyNotFoundException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : PropertyNotFoundStrict
```

#### Unstrict Mode Results

When I turn strict mode off:

```
Set-StrictMode -Off
```

PowerShell converts both of the locations to objects. The missing property is null:

```
LocationCode         : 7188
LocationName         : Tirana Airport
Latitude             : 41.42108838
Longitude            : 19.71271276
CountryCode          : AL
FormattedAddress     : Tirana Airport Muhamet Gjollesha Str., Muhamet Gjollesha Str., Tirana
CityName             : Tirana
ServesAirport        : 1
AirportCode          : TIA
ServesRailwayStation : 0

LocationCode         : 30768
LocationName         : Tirana Downtown
Latitude             : 41.332
Longitude            : 19.832
CountryCode          : AL
FormattedAddress     : Rruga E Durresit. Nr 61, Tirana
CityName             : Tirana
ServesAirport        : 0
AirportCode          : 
ServesRailwayStation : 0
```

#### Is there a better way?

I don't want to turn off strict mode to make this work if there is a better way.

Anything that works in strict mode is acceptable. I've been looking for something like a [T-SQL CASE expression](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms181765.aspx), or [Python's dict get method](http://docs.python.org/2/library/stdtypes.html#dict.get). Maybe there is a XPath way to do it as well.

Comment: Is `($n | select AirportCode).AirportCode` an acceptable workaround?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your case it's easy :

```
select-Xml -Xml $InputXml -XPath '//ns:Location' -Namespace @{ns = 'http://www.cartrawler.com/'} |
% {
  $n = $_.Node

  [PSCustomObject] @{
    LocationCode = $n.Id
    LocationName = $n.Name
    Latitude = $n.Lat
    Longitude = $n.Lng
    CountryCode = $n.CountryCode
    FormattedAddress = $n.Address
    CityName = $n.CityName
    ServesAirport = $n.Airport
    AirportCode = $(if($n.Airport -eq '1'){$n.AirportCode}else{""})
    ServesRailwayStation = $n.RailwayStation
  }
}
```

More generaly :

```
select-Xml -Xml $InputXml -XPath '//ns:Location' -Namespace @{ns = 'http://www.cartrawler.com/'} |
% {
  $n = $_.Node

  [PSCustomObject] @{
    LocationCode = $n.Id
    LocationName = $n.Name
    Latitude = $n.Lat
    Longitude = $n.Lng
    CountryCode = $n.CountryCode
    FormattedAddress = $n.Address
    CityName = $n.CityName
    ServesAirport = $n.Airport
    AirportCode = $(if($n.GetAttributeNode("AirportCode") -ne $null){$n.AirportCode}else{""})
    ServesRailwayStation = $n.RailwayStation
  }
}
```

Once this written, my old programer opinion (the kind you don't care) is that if you want to use strict mode just stop scripting and begin to write java, C#, C or C++. The kind of approximation you are fighting with strict mode IS the + of scripting which is for me quicly resolv a problem on the corner of the table. My opinion is that using strict mode brings all the drawback of conventional programming without the interests, but it's just my opinion.

Comment: An "Aha!" moment. I wished I had something like [C's ternary operator (`?:`)](http://publications.gbdirect.co.uk/c_book/chapter3/strange_operators.html). The `$(if(){}else{})` appears to be PowerShell's equivalent.

Comment: I value your opinion. Strict mode of course has it place for catching unintended errors, but I shouldn't obsess about it. I prefer the elegance of the unstrict solution, it does exactly what I want, and it's easier to understand. Thanks for showing me how to do it strictly, but in the end I might be better to loosen up the syntax.

Comment: @IainElder You're [not alone](http://connect.microsoft.com/PowerShell/feedback/details/53059/add-ternary-operator-to-script-language) with that wish.

Comment: Isn't this still causing the same exception to be raised?

Comment: That's not the case in my test. Have you got an exception ?